# How to fade out a div, then fade in another in the same location. CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am trying to fade a div out and then fade another div in to replace it once it has completely faded using CSS only. However, both divs still seem to keep their space on the page once they have faded out. The only way I can seem to get rid of their space is with `display: none;`, but this isn't animatable. At the moment, I am using CSS animation to alter the opacity of the elements, e.g.:

```
.first {
  animation: fadeOut 8s ease;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity:1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity:0;
  }
}
```

[Here is a fiddle with what I have so far.](https://jsfiddle.net/ovbker8w/) As you can see, the 3 columns fade in below, not in-place of the faded out button.
For more context, I have 3 columns, vertically centred, except for on mobile where they are stacked. The button that is display on page load should be vertically and horizontally centred.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish when people down-grade a question, they'd put up their reason.  May give the question asker a lead.  No?

Comment: I did not down vote, however, most of the time is because the question (like this one), does not contain the minimal example as required by Stack Overflow guidelines. The CSS is not nearly enough. The question states there is other code, but links to a fiddle. That code should be in question itself and not another offsite resource.

Comment: @disinfor Thank you for explaining.  I hope the OP follows the guidelines.  Sometimes we just don't read all the rules.  I am scared to ask questions on here, because there are those who hang out almost full-time on stackoverflow and are quite aware of shortfalls.  But there are also those, although the question is ambiguous, they may pick up on the underlying problem and can fish out a code they used before.  A debate for a separate question  ;)

Comment: @Mugé no problem. It's not even really reading all the rules. There is a really good help section that's pretty short, yet thorough. https://stackoverflow.com/help You should never be afraid to ask a question here! Here's a basic guideline that I like to follow: if someone came up to you asking for help, what would be the minimum information they would need to provide for you to answer? That's the best place to start when asking a question. Questions like this (as currently written) is like walking into an auto shop saying "my car makes a noise" and walking out, giving no other information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` for the two DIVs to allow them to be both at the same position. (and `position: relative` for the parent DIV to make it serve as the position anchor)